# Wearing a tie on Tisha B'Av

Tags: clothing, tisha-bav

Is there an issue with wearing a tie on Tisha B'Av? Some Rabbonim who normally wear a tie throughout the week take it off for Tisha B'Av. For instance, see Rav Moshe Tuvia Lieff [here](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=157653) without a tie during kinnos [as well as](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=157154) Rav Shraga Kallus, yet Rav Yosef Viener [does](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=157579) wear a tie [as well as](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=157358) Rav Daniel Glatstein. (I would have thought wearing an older/less appealing tie was ok)

Comment: [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/149580/jewish/The-Laws-of-Mourning-on-Tisha-BAv.htm) writes "We don't wear fine festive clothing". I would have imagined someone who wears a tie normally can do so on TbAv as well, but someone who doesn't shouldn't put one on. But I don't have a formal source for this yet

Comment: Surely this is community specific. There is no siman in shulchan aruch about "ties".

Comment: I've seen people do it both ways. Upon further questioning, the ones who don't said they felt a tie was meant as an honorable piece of clothing since they don't wear it in their home. The ones who did compared it to a shirt, nobody just wears an undershirt, because that's called being dressed. To them a tie was a basic garment that that wear always even at home.

Comment: From dinonline - How should one dress for shul?
One should wear plain weekday clothes as a sign of mourning. Men should not wear a tie and women should not wear jewelry. Some have a custom to wear old clothes that are torn or ragged.

Comment: @Chatzkel You should make this an answer

Comment: @sabbahillel I thought about that, but the question is showing different rabbis doing things and I didn't think it's correct for me to offer reasons as to why they do or don't do things. I guess I'll preface that before the answer

Answer (score 1):

At the behest of Sabbahillel I am attempting an answer with a preface - the question is showing different rabbonim doing opposite things and they each obviously have their own reasons why they do what they do. All I am saying is that while I can't say why they did or didn't wear a tie, he is what I've heard in the past.

I've seen people do it both ways. Upon further questioning, the ones who don't said they felt a tie was meant as an honorable piece of clothing since they don't wear it in their home. The ones who did compared it to a shirt, nobody just wears an undershirt, because that's called being dressed. To them a tie was a basic garment that that wear always even at home.

Additionally, I've found on dinonline the following:

> How should one dress for shul? One should wear plain weekday clothes as a sign of mourning. Men should not wear a tie and women should not wear jewelry. Some have a custom to wear old clothes that are torn or ragged.

Although obviously this is not the minhag of all